# WTForms - multi-value string to SelectMultipleField

Tags: python, multivalue, wtforms

I have a WTForm called `TestForm` with the following property:

```
areas = SelectMultipleField(u'Test Areas', choices=TestArea.names())
```

When I create a new instance of `TestForm` and pass in an object with an `areas` property, the object doesn't have a list of values for `areas`, but rather a string with a value like `Area1;Area2;Area3`.  How can I go about translating between the list `['Area1', 'Area2', 'Area3']` that the `SelectMultipleField` expects, and the string that my object expects to find in `areas`?  I have several of these fields, so I would prefer not to have to pass in something like `TestForm(areas=myObj.areas.split(';'), field2=myObj.field2.split(';'), ..., myObj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround for now is to have the following setup in my SQLAlchemy model:

```
areas = Column(u'AREAS', VARCHAR(80))

@property
def areasList(self):
    return self.areas.split(';')

@areasList.setter
def areasList(self, areas):
    self.areas = ';'.join(areas)
```

Then in my WTForms form:

```
areasList = SelectMultipleField(u'Test Areas', choices=TestArea.names())
```